# c# Assert.Contains from ValidationResult UNIT TESTS

Tags: c#, unit-testing

For some MODEL checks I am using ValidationContext to return the errors.
This part works fine for the functional aspects.
I am now creating some UNIT TESTS and wanting to test that for certain scenarios, the relevant error message is contained in the results - without caring too much about any other error messages e.g. just wanting to ensure that at least a specific error is returned.

Example:
From the model validation call in the [Fact] Test, I use:

```
        ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(propDets);
        IEnumerable<ValidationResult> results = propDets.Validate(validationContext);
```

where propDets is the MODEL I want to validate.

I get similar to the following returned as a list:

results
Count = 3

```
[0]: {'numberOfFloors' is mandatory when the Property Type is 'Flat'.}
[1]: {'serviceCharge' is not required when the Tenure is 'Freehold'.}
[2]: {'groundRent' is not required when the Tenure is 'Freehold'.}
```

I was trying to use:

```
Assert.Contains<ValidationResult>(...)
```

But couldn't get the syntax correct e.g. to find where the results SET contains the errorMessage:
"'serviceCharge' is not required when the Tenure is 'Freehold'."

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: Assert.NotEmpty
Link: https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it isn't specifically checking for the error e.g. in the above example if I was specifically testing for serviceCharge is not required... - but a different error was there but this one wasn't, then this TEST would still pass - but incorrectly.

Comment: If your method trows errors which are NOT expected - you should not make any additional checks for exceptions. It will be performed by xunit. Otherwise you should use Assert.Throws<ex> @Woody